# NIO endless loop of OP_READ

Tags: java, nio

I have a NIO problem in Java.I am trying writing a read TCP data stream program.`TCPDemoNIO`  is the code.The problem is:
**when data coming, it can read first,but then OP_READ is always triggered.So the while loop is an endless loop.There is high CPU usage.**

I debug the code,`channel.read(buffer)` is returning -1.Why there is OP_READ event?

```java
public class TCPDemoNIO {
        SocketChannel socket = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 7890));

        socket.configureBlocking(true);
        System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress());
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.socket().getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(new byte[]{5, 0, 1});
        outputStream.flush();
        ByteBuffer allocate1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(17);
        byte[] b = {5, 1, 0, 3};
        allocate1.put(b);
        allocate1.put("a.baidu.com".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        allocate1.put(new byte[]{00, 80});
        allocate1.flip();
        outputStream.write(allocate1.array());
        outputStream.flush();
        socket.configureBlocking(false);
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        socket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        ByteBuffer allocate = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
        while (true) {
        
            if (selector.select(500) == 0) {
                System.out.print(".");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print("x");
            Thread.sleep(500);

            Set<SelectionKey> selectionKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selectionKeys.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    int read;
                    allocate.clear();
                    while ((read = channel.read(allocate)) > 0) {
                        allocate.flip();
                        System.out.print(Charset.forName("utf-8").decode(allocate));
                        allocate.clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            selectionKeys.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean that:   selector.select(500)   always return 1 , but read(allocate) return -1. 
Is that a conflict?

Comment: `while (true)` is an infinite loop that you never `break` out of.

Comment: @Abra emmm,Yeah  , `while(true)` is used to receive data from TCP stream forever, I think there no problem. When I read **all data** from TCP stream, I don't know that: why `selector.select()` return 1.

Comment: outer while loop to receive data forever , inner while loop is used to process OP_READ event. If use `break` in the outer loop, the program can't receive any more data.

Comment: You are almost certainly looping at end of stream. If `read()` returns -1 you should close the socket.